# How to understand Keras 1D Convolution input shape and filter

Tags: neural-network, time-series, conv-neural-network, forecasting

I spent some time to understand `input_shape = (batch_size, steps, input_dim)` in Keras Conv1D, but I cannot make any progress so far.

To be more specific, I have 2 datasets.

*Dataset-1*: Solar energy production of 24 hours of each day in one year, so the size of my dataset is (364,24), days are in row and consumption is in columns.

Example of 2 days:

```
day-1: [0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1.611   5.791   8.229   9.907   9.649   8.401   6.266   4.728   2.231   0.306   0.013   0   0   0   0   0   0] 
day-2: [0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1.732   5.839   9.909   12.593  14.242  12.744  9.596   5.808   2.019   0.241   0   0   0   0   0   0   0]`
```

What I want to do with CNN is using 6 days' data to predict the 7th day.
for that reason, I divided my dataset like so:

```
xtrain = dataset[0:6,0:24] # takes 24 hour of 6 days
ytrain = dataset[6,0:24] # takes 24 hour of 7th day
xtest = dataset[1:7,0:24] # takes 24 hours for 6 days (day2 to day7) to predict day 8
```

To be compatible with Keras' input shape, I reshaped the training data as follows:

```
xtrain = xtrain.reshape(6,1,24)
```

Number of Samples: 6, Time Dimension: 1, input_dimension:24

Is this correct thinking?

```
model.add(Conv1D(**filters?**,kernel_size=4,activation='relu', **input_shape=?**))
```

In my second dataset:

```
Training Data: Xtrain: Day-1 Hour-1 to Hour-24, Day-2 Hour-1 to Hour-24 ... Day-6 Hour-1 to Hour-24
Ytrain: Day-7 Hour-1 to Hour-24
```

I have created a new dataset which takes 24 hours of a day in the rows and 7 days in the columns, so it is a (8616,7) matrix.

```
hour-1 day-1, day-2 ... day-7
hour-2 day-1, day-2 ... day-7
...
hour-24 day-1, day-2 ... day-7
...
hour-1 day-2, day-3 ... day-8
hour-2 day-2, day-3 ... day-8
...
hour-24 day-2, day-3 ... day-8
...
hour-1 day-359, day-360 ... day-365
hour-2 day-359, day-360 ... day-365
...
hour-24 day-359, day-360 ... day-365
```

Keras Code:

```
xtrain = dataset[0:24,0:6] # takes 24 hour for 6 days
ytrain = dataset[24:48,6] # takes 24 hour of 7th day
xtest = dataset[24:48,0:6] # takes 24 hours for 6 days (day2 to day7) to predict day 7

xtrain = xtrain[newaxis,:, :]
ytrain = ytrain.reshape(1,24)
```

I really don't understand what filters and input_shape should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should reformat your dataset in a structure like this:

[365,6,24]

The first dimension sets the day.

The second dimensions set the timestep (the progression over the 6 days), so you should take each day of the original dataset 6:365 and then copy the past 6 days 24h.

The third dimension is each hour

Assuming that you have your original dataset of [1:365,1:24] ordered:

> xtrain=np.array(np.tile(xtrain,[6 1]))
>
> xtrain=np.reshape(xtrain,(365,6,24))

And then now you have the required 3D format for conv1d (batch, timesteps, channels)